# How to assign default value to select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project where I need to show select option in the edit field with the value in it.

1) To get all dropdown values I have an API the response is in the screenshot.
[image: Get all dropdown options values]

2) When I click on Edit I am calling another API where I will get the saved value in API response in which I need to assign **MasterData** ie File Servers should be defaultly selected in the dropdown:

[image]

I am trying to use ng-init to acheive this. Below is my code.

```
<select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" ng-init="question.MasterData = questionnaireDataEditDefault" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; white-space:pre-wrap;">
                                <option selected="selected"></option>
                                <option ng-repeat="answer in answerData[question.MasterDataCategoryId]" value="{{answer.MasterData}}">{{answer.MasterData}}</option>

                            </select>
```

Can anyone let me know how to acheive this.

Comment: use `ngOptions` instead of `ngRepeat` to bind the `select` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

After getting response from another API, assign that new value to **`selected`** as - `$scope.selected = response.value`, where **`response.value`** will be your real object

Comment: I will be getting many options like that I have attached the screenshot of it. And what to menstion in ng-init?